# Error in Java Expression

Tags: java

Does the following Java statement have an error in it? If so, what is it?

```
P *= x/y
```

Comment: What are the types of the variables?

Comment: You're missing a semicolon. Also, the rest of the program. Some context would be useful.

Comment: i hav to find logical errors..

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for "logical errors" and if the types are all integers, it's probably better to do:

```
P = (P*x)/y;
```

Because the current expression (IIRC) is equivalent to:

```
P = P*(x/y);
```

The latter expression may be less "accurate" if the types are integers.  For example:

```
// evaluates to 3, as expected.
(5*3)/5;
```

However,

```
// Evaluates to 0 because of truncation.
5*(3/5);
```

So you need to be careful.  In general division on integer expressions should be done as the final step.

Comment: Wouldn't your first example (5*3)/5 evaluate to 3?
5*3=15 15/5 = 3

Comment: @Mike C
Oops, you're right, a careless mistake on my part, will correct it.

Answer (score 0):

It lacks a semicolon

If there's more errors, it depends on the types of P,x and y. They have to be number types

Answer (score 0):

Looks perfectly fine apart from the aforementioned lack of a semicolon, and possible problems with type. That statement just divides x by y, multiplies that result by p, and places that value into p. `p = (p*(x/y));`

Answer (score 0):

If `P` is a primitive numeric data type (float, double, int, etc) it should probably be in lowercase. Uppercase variable names are typically reserved for constants in Java.

Also, since it translates to `(P*(x/y))`, if `x` and `y` where `int` and `P` were `float` or `double`, you might not get the answer you expect.